# how does memory allocation for postgres work?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

1. shared_buffers - In a regular PostgreSQL installation, say I am allocating 25% of my memory to shared_buffers that means it leaves 75% for rest such as OS, page cache and work_mems etc. Is my understanding correct?
   If so, AWS Aurora for Postgres uses 75% of memory for shared_buffers, then it would leave just 25% for other things?
2. Does the memory specified for work_mem, fully gets allocated to all sessions irrespective of whether they do any sorting or hashing operations?

Comment: Aurora is quite different than plain PostgreSQL.  I don't think it has a page cache as such, so for Aurora it is just shared_buffers and work_mem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first statement is necessarily true:

**If** 75% of the RAM are used for shared buffers, **then** only 25% are available for other things like process private memory.

`work_mem` is the *upper limit* of memory that one operation (“node”) in an execution plan is ready to use for operations like creating a hash or a bitmap or sorting. That does not mean that every operation allocates that much memory, it is just a limit.

Without any claim for absolute reliability, here is my personal rule of thumb:

`shared_buffers` + `max_connections` * `work_mem` should be less or equal to the RAM available. Then you are unlikely to run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks, for q2 - if work_mem is a limit, is there a min amount of memory which gets allocated to each session?

Comment: Just what is required to cache the system catalogs, a couple of MB.